# Prevent overlapping elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

This question has been asked before, however each situation is unique. I have a screenshot of a website that has a login box (registration box) with a sticky note on the side to tell the users what information to enter.

Screenshot below:

[image]

The registration box is over lapping the sticky note when the user resizes his browser window. Also the login box is overlapping the logo on the top. A solution that is cross compatible with many browsers would be nice (if possible).

Here is my CSS:

```
    .box
    {
        background:#fefefe;
        border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
        border-top:1px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
        -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
        -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
        box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
        color:#444;
        font:normal 12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        margin:0 auto 30px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .box.login
    {
            height:480px;
            width:332px;
            position:absolute;
            left:50%;
            top:37%;
            margin:-130px 0 0 -166px;
    }
    .boxBody
    {
        background:#fefefe;
        border-top:1px solid #dde0e8;
        padding:10px 20px;
    }

    .box footer
    {
        background:#eff4f6;
        border-top:1px solid #dde0e8;
        padding:22px 26px;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:32px;
    }
    .box label
    {
        display:block;
        font:14px/22px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        margin:10px 0 0 6px;
    }
    .box footer label{
            float:left;
            margin:4px 0 0;
    }
    .box footer input[type=checkbox]{
            vertical-align:sub;
            *vertical-align:middle;
            margin-right:10px;
.sticky {
    /* General */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 8px 24px;
  /*width: 370px; */
    max-width: 370px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
    position: fixed;
    left: 3%;
    top: 35%;
    /* Font */
    font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    /* Border */
    border:1px #E8Ds47 solid;
    /* Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
    /* Background */
    background: #fefdca; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefdca), c$
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safar$
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefdca', endColor$
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%,#f7f381 100%); /* W3C; A catch-all for ev$
}

.sticky ol {
    margin: 12px;
}

.sticky p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Secure Customer Login</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0$
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure_register.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nothing+You+Could+Do' rel='styleshe$
  <script>document.createElement('footer');</script>
</head>
<center><img src="/images/logo.png"></center>
<body>
<div class="sticky">
    <p>
    <strong>Please Note</strong>
    <br />
    </p>
    <ol>
        <li>Please use your real name (your information is secure and will NOT be shared)$
        <li>Capitalize the first letter of your first name and last name (i.e. John Doe)<$
        <li>Use your email address for the username, otherwise you will not be able to ac$
        <li>Use a secure password that cannot be easily guessed</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<form class="box login" name="register" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" meth$
  <fieldset class="boxBody">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="50" tabindex="1" placeholder="First Na$
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" placeholder="Last Name$
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="email" name="username" maxlength="50" tabindex="3" placeholder="Email" r$
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass1" tabindex="4" />
    <label>Repeat Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="pass2" tabindex="5" />
</fieldset>
  <footer>
    <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btnLogin" /></cent$
  </footer>
</form>
<footer id="main">
  &copy; 2014 Rye High Group.  All rights reserved.</a>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Your help is very much appreciated, I love this community!

Thanks,

Fixnode

Comment: How about css for .sticky?

Comment: could you please make this in a fiddle and we can try to fix it? Also,  if you are looking for responsive, then you need to use media queries. Avoid using pixels as they are fixed and won't change when you resize the browser

Comment: `<center>` element is deprecated! You should use CSS instead of HTML for styling purposes, in this case, `text-align: center`. And why do you put it BEFORE `<body>`?

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: As jbyrd says, you aren't asking anything. You just say that you don't like the current behavior, but don't say which is the desired one.

Comment: @Oriol I know '<center>' is depreciated but this is old code. I hate using CSS so thats why I centered the main logo in HTML.

Comment: @jbyrd The question is in the title of the thread. How to prevent overlapping of these 2 elements .sticky and .box login. I never used fiddle, I'll do that for next time.

Comment: @fixnode OMG, really? Are you a HTML-only web developer, no CSS? Then I'm sorry, but you can't code good-loking pages with just HTML :)

Comment: @fixnode Your question is not clear enough because you don't say if the note and the image should overlap the box (currently is the opposite) or if you want to move them to prevent overlapping.

Comment: you should add an image of what you want, your question is too vague

Comment: @Oriol The sticky note should automatically resize itself when a browser window is resized horizontally. The registration form should resize itself (to prevent the image from overlapping) when the browser window is vertically resized. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I'm a back end developer mostly in Microsoft SQL Server with knowledge in PHP and HTML, sorry we can't all be creative developers. Here is the link to JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fixnode/va45t/

Comment: @arieljuod the image is above. I want everything to resize itself. Also the link to jsfiddle is in the previous post

Comment: the image shows the problem, not the desired result, if you want thing to resize you need to use max-height and max-width with % values, you may want to read about responsive design too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ab5KN/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="img">
    <img src="http://rye-high.ca/images/logo.png" />
</div>
<div class="sticky">
    <p> <strong>Please Note</strong>

        <br />
    </p>
    <ol>
        <li>Please use your real name (your information is secure and will NOT be shared)    </li>
        <li>Capitalize the first letter of your first name and last name (i.e. John Doe)</li>
        <li>Use your email address for the username, otherwise you will not be able to access your account</li>
        <li>Use a secure password that cannot be easily guessed</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="box">
<form class="login" name="register" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset class="boxBody">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="50" tabindex="1" placeholder="First Name" required />
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" placeholder="Last Name" required />
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="email" name="username" maxlength="50" tabindex="3" placeholder="Email" required />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass1" tabindex="4" />
        <label>Repeat Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="pass2" tabindex="5" />
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
        <center>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btnLogin" />
        </center>
    </footer>
</form>
</div>
<footer id="main">&copy; 2014 Rye High Group. All rights reserved.</a>
</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#eff3f6;
    width: 1000px;
}
.img {
    /*display: block;*/
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
    width:332px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background:#fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
    border-top:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0 0 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0 0 1px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0 0 1px;
    color:#444;
    font:normal 12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    /*margin:0 auto 30px;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    position: block;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.box.login {
    height:480px;
    width:150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.login fieldset{
    border: 0px;
}
.boxBody {
    background:#fefefe;
    border-top:1px solid #dde0e8;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
.box footer {
    background:#eff4f6;
    border-top:1px solid #dde0e8;
    padding:22px 26px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:32px;
}
.box label {
    display:block;
    font:14px/22px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    margin:10px 0 0 6px;
}
.box footer label {
    float:left;
    margin:4px 0 0;
}
.box footer input[type=checkbox] {
    vertical-align:sub;
    *vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:10px;
}
/*Alert Box*/
 .alert {
    background: #fff6bf url(../images/exclamation.png) center no-repeat;
    background-position: 15px 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffd324;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffd324;
}
.info {
    background: #CDFECD url(../images/information.png) center no-repeat;
    background-position: 15px 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
    border-top: 2px solid #90EE90;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #90EE90;
}
.error {
    background: #FFBFBF url(../images/error.png) center no-repeat;
    background-position: 15px 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FF2424;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF2424;
}
.box input[type=email], .box input[type=password], .box input[type=text], .txtField, .cjComboBox {
    border:6px solid #F7F9FA;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95a2a7 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95a2a7 inset;
    box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95a2a7 inset;
    margin:3px 0 4px;
    padding:8px 6px;
    width:270px;
    display:block;
}
.box input[type=email]:focus, .box input[type=password]:focus, .box input[type=text]:focus, .txtField:focus, .cjComboBox:focus {
    border:6px solid #f0f7fc;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset, 0 0 1px #0d6db6 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset, 0 0 1px #0d6db6 inset;
    box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset, 0 0 1px #0d6db6 inset;
    color:#333;
}
.cjComboBox {
    width:294px;
}
.cjComboBox.small {
    padding:3px 2px 3px 6px;
    width:100px;
    border-width:3px !important;
}
.txtField.small {
    padding:3px 6px;
    width:200px;
    border-width:3px !important;
}
.rLink {
    padding:0 6px 0 0;
    font-size:11px;
    float:right;
}
.box a {
    color:#999;
}
.box a:hover, .box a:focus {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.box a:active {
    color:#f84747;
}
.btnLogin {
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:#a1d8f0;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #badff3, #7acbed);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#badff3), to(#7acbed));
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#badff3', EndColorStr='#7acbed')";
    border:1px solid #7db0cc !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:11px 16px;
    font:bold 11px/14px Verdana, Tahomma, Geneva;
    text-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 1px 0px;
    color:#fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0 1px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 1px 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0 1px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow:inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0 1px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 1px 1px;
    margin-left:12px;
    padding:7px 21px;
}
.btnLogin:hover, .btnLogin:focus, .btnLogin:active {
    background:#a1d8f0;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #7acbed, #badff3);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7acbed), to(#badff3));
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#7acbed', EndColorStr='#badff3')";
}
.btnLogin:active {
    text-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 -1px 0px;
}
footer#main {
    /*position:fixed;*/
    left:0;
    bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font:normal 11px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
}
.sticky {
    /* General */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 8px 4px;
    /*width: 370px; */
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    top: 250px;
    /* Font */
    font-family:'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    font-size: 1em;
    /* Border */
    border:1px #E8Ds47 solid;
    /* Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 1px #333333;
    /* Background */
    background: #fefdca;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefdca), color-stop(100%, #f7f381));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
    /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fefdca', endColorstr='#f7f381', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fefdca 0%, #f7f381 100%);
    /* W3C; A catch-all for everything else */
}
/*.sticky ol {
    margin: 12px;
}*/
.sticky p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Basically I added a width to the body, or else adjusting the size of the window will always cause something to overlap. I also added in div wrappers around the image and form (not sure if really needed but added for what I consider better structure). Took out some of the positioning css as well as it causes undue pain when trying to do things.

Comment: I want the site to be dynamic, by making the body width 1000px it fixes all the elements in one spot. Also Jfiddle doesn't represent the site properly. Everything is shown slightly to the left.

Comment: After looking at the site some more, I would recommend getting rid of the sticky, and then going with sized div's around the content and using `margin: 0 auto;` to make sure they are centered in the page. I would then take all of the items of the sticky, and only use the 1st and 4th item, and put them as "helper" text to or below the inputs.  Item 2 could be done with javascript so you could format their name for them after leaving the input, and Item number 3 needs to be a validation that is performed to prevent users from entering bad data in the first place.

Comment: the `margin: 0 auto;` was just a suggestion, as long as the left and right of the margin are auto, the top and bottom can be whatever you want them to be.

Comment: you might be right, I might just remove the sticky and implement a validation script for items 2 and 3 and for item 4 I will make password rules and implement them via javascript. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule:

```
.box
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question and added the .sticky code. Your current answer makes the .sticky element overlap the registration box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fixnode/va45t/

Comment: So where would you like to put .sticky?

Comment: if possible make it automatically resize if it touches the .box login element

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

I removed your position absolute styles and added a wrapper around the sticky and the login controls and applied `float:left` and `float: right` on them.

The wrapper itself is center aligned to the page.

I edited the fiddle you posted in the comment on a previous answer and updated it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/va45t/1/

```
#wrapper {
    width: 720px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The other styles changed were `.box.login` and `.sticky`